# How can I get a null or blank value in STR_TO_DATE() select statement?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have multiple columns with time values in string format(e.g 2:00 PM) that I want to convert to `datetime`(e.g 14:00). I have used this code example `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(myColumnOne, %H:%i'), STR_TO_DATE(myColumnTwo, %H:%i') FROM myTableName;`
The problem is that I have some `blank` values in `myColumns` which are being converted to `00:00`. This will cause problems later as they'll be recognized as midnight time(i.e 12:00 AM).
How can I maintain the values to be blank or null after the conversion? *Plus: I have some actual, genuine times that are like 12:00 AM which are supposed to be converted to 00:00*

Comment: *time values in string format(e.g 2:00 PM) that I want to convert to datetime(e.g 14:00)* DATETIME cannot store this value. Use TIME datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(time_as_string, ''), '%h:%i %p')
FROM data_table
```

NULLIF() converts "blank values" (empty string) to NULL.

STR_TO_DATE() converts the string value to TIME datatype value.